# How to run MATLAB in bash shell REALLY quiet?

Tags: linux, bash, matlab

I'm using MATLAB in a Makefile to convert some data to eps.
But it's displaying it's logo all over the place.

For instance, when I type into bash:

```
matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r "display('derp');exit"
```

I get:

```
                        < M A T L A B (R) >
              Copyright 1984-2012 The MathWorks, Inc.
                R2012a (7.14.0.739) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                          February 9, 2012



 To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
 For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.

 derp
```

I understand that MATLAB isn't python that can just

```
python -c "print 'zoom'"
```

but is there any way to make it stop printing the MATLAB logo?

Comment: `matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r "display('derp');exit" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null` ?

Comment: That just supresses all output. The point is to print everything except the logo.

Comment: `matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r "display('derp');exit" | tail -n +6`. Although I don't think the logo is so annoying :)

Comment: It's annoying when you're reading half a page of make output that actually matters and it's interweaved with MATLAB logos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not a matlab expert but you can always do something as ugly as:

```
matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r "display('derp');exit" | tail -n +10
```

Note that the "+10" may change according to your Matlab version or license. For a Classroom license, there are 3 extra lines for instance.

Comment: Not bad, although I'd prefer some secret MATLAB switch. I now just have to hope that MATLAB will print the logo ALWAYS (otherwise i'll skip 10 lines of my output:)

Comment: Yes, I hope so too :). But I don't have matlab on my computer so that's the best I can do right now. (Hum, I may have an access to matlab through the VPN of my uni, I'll try)